# for t-sql intellisense in visual studio 2010, why do I have to prefix tablename with database name

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've picked LocalDB in the dropdown for "Database:"

If I type:

```
select * from mnt.
```

(I don't get intellisense)

I have to type:

```
select * from LocalDB.mnt.
```

or

```
use LocalDB

select * from mnt.
```

I don't have this problem in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Just tested this and unfortunately I have to say, "works on my machine" - intellisense worked as expected.

Comment: it's working for me now... must be a "sometimes" bug :)

Answer (score 0):

If its a newly created object or schema, then it could be some time befor the local cache of the objects are refreshed. Atleast thats the case with SQL Mgmt Studio. In SQL Mgmt Studio, you can do Edit>Intellisense>Refresh Local Cache.

I wonder if there's a similar option in VS.